# How to append multiple records in MySQL Database with crudRepository using Spring-data-JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using POST method to insert new records one by one but I am looking forward to push multiple records at a time. My code for single insert is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/users")
public class MainController {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@PostMapping(path="/add", consumes="application/json", produces = "application/json")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestBody UserFormDto userForm) {
    User n = new User();
    n.setName(userForm.getName());
    n.setEmail(userForm.getEmail());
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "\n\t\t Saved";
}
}
```

Entity Class is as follow: Any help will be much appriciatted

```
package hello;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Entity
public class User {

private String name;
private String email;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

public User() {
}

public User(String email,String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you get multiple Users? Your method `addNewUser()` takes only one user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793403/crudrepository-and-hibernate-savelists-vs-saveentity-in-transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need batch insert update. Check this [Spring Data JPA performnace issue with batch save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899662/spring-data-jpa-performnace-issue-with-batch-save)
 and this
https://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/

Answer (score 1):

Spring curdRepository provides the method

```
 <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> entities);
```

using this method you can put the user objects in collection and than save collection object,i hope these help

example:

```
List<Student> list= new ArrayList<Student>();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setName("asd");
    student.setPercentage(66.66);
    student.setTotal(200);

list.add(student);
}
//Saves the list of Student Object
repository.save(list);
}
```

put all your Objects in a list and then use save() of curdRepository to bulk save.

Comment: Can you please explain the function parameters?

Comment: check the answer i have edited it will give you complete idea.